# What's a good IntelliJ Inspection Profile, ROI wise?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, intellij-idea, code-analysis

IntelliJ Code Inspections (and code analysis in general) tends to gather a lot of different issues of varying usefulness. Some with high ROI to fix, like null pointer exceptions, and other more subtle inspections, like Declaration Access Can Be Weaker.

Are you using code inspections in your continuous integration? What is a good inspection profile for that? (Yes, I know that this might change between teams, but I'd like to start with a good baseline that catches real bugs, with as few false positives as possible).

Answer (score 2):

It's highly dependent upon java technologies used in your project and project itself. Project, as a term, is defined as 'new , unique piece of work, etc etc'. This uniqueness applies downwards to project management tools like IntelliJ's Code inspections.

For example, Serialization inspections are mostly useless for general purposes but becomes critical and save lot of time when it comes to distributed J2EE applications. 'Method never used' inspection is good in plain java programming but is annoying for getter/setter methods required by application containers (JSF, JPA, etc).

But even having your technologies defined and inspections tuned accordingly, that wont save you from continuous adapting of inspection profiles according to project management regular reporting, problem analysis, etc. Especially for big and long-lasting projects.